# AWS DynamoDB GetItem using index in step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

I have a DynamoDB table with the following characteristics (names changed for security reasons)-

TableName - ABC

Index - XYZ-index (This is a global secondary index(GSI))

partition key for index - XYZ

I have a state in a step function that looks like this -

```
"STATE NAME": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:getItem",
              "Parameters": {
                "TableName": "ABC",
                "IndexName": "XYZ-index",
                "Key": {
                  "XYZ": {
                    "S.$": "$.Main.Item.Request.ID"
                  }
                }
              },
              "ResultPath": "$.SOME_PATH",
              "Next": "NEXT STATE"
            }
```

I am trying to use this state of the step function to get an item from the DynamoDB table using one of its indexes. When I try to save the state machine, I get an error that field IndexName is not supported.

So how do I get an item from a DynamoDB table by querying a GSI of the table within a state of a step function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use Query Api for GSI and I believe state machines only support Get, Put, Update and Delete DynamoDB item [APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ddb.html) but not Query.
IndexName is not an option in getItem.